# I have issue in the odd number part

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Query on a Solution to problem:
If a is odd, then gcd(3a,3a+2)=1.
I tried to put a=2k+1 to be an odd number. But it does not solved.

Comment: $\gcd(3a,3a+2)=\gcd(3a,2)$, and, if $a$ is odd, then $\gcd(3a,2)=1$

Comment: Why would you put $a=2a+1$?

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: $a=2a+1$ implies $a=-1$.  Why would you assume that?

Comment: Sorry it's rong from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux is to know $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)=\gcd(b,b-a)=\gcd(b,a-b)$, or more generally, the Euclidean algorithm: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a\bmod b)$

So, we have $$\begin{align}\gcd(3a,3a+2)&=\gcd(3a,3a+2-3a)\\&=\gcd(3a,2)\\&=\gcd(2,3a)=\gcd(2,3a-2a)=\gcd(2,a)\end{align}$$

which equals 2 when $a$ is even and 1 when $a$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

By familiar properties of $\gcd$,
$$\gcd(3a+2, 3a) = \gcd((3a + 2) - 3a, 3a) = \gcd(2, 3a)  \text{.}  $$
Since $a$ and $3$ are odd, $3a$ is odd.  $2$ is prime, so $\gcd(2, 3a) > 1$ only if $2$ divides $3a$, but $2$ divides no odd number.  Therefore, $\gcd(2,3a) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Euclidean Algorithm we have the following chain of pairs:
\begin{gather*}
(3a+2,3a)\\
(3a,2) \\
(2,1).
\end{gather*}

This implies that $\gcd(3a+2,3a) = 1$.